# No puedo hacer post Node js Router Express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, router

Estoy usando Express y Router para crear las ligas de mi api, pero por alguna razón cuando intento hacer **post** me tira un error **404**
, pero si me encuentra cualquier **get**. Cuando reviso la consola del explorador puedo ver que si hace el post con los parámetros de mi form, pero no encuentra la ruta

```js
// rutas de ligas

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const pool = require('../../db');


router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
  res.render('links/add');
});

router.get('/x', (req, res) => {
  res.send('x');
});

router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('recibido');
});


module.exports = router;
```

```html
<form action="/links/adds" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Nombre Del Proyecto</label><br>
    <input style="width: 50%;" type="text" name="name" autofocus><br>

    <label for="">URL</label><br>
    <input style="width: 50%;" type="url" name="url" autofocus><br>

    <label for="">Descripción</label><br>
    <textarea style="width: 100%;" name="descrip" placeholder="Descripción de proyecto">
                                    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-secondary   pull-right">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo en tu form que estás poniendo el método post que apunte a '/links/add'. Sin embargo en tu configuración del router capturas solo '/add'.
Puedes empezar por ver si allí está el problema.
Saludos.

Otra cosa: en el router captura post hacia '/add' sin embargo en el form lo envías hacia '/links/adds'. Verifica la letra 's' adicional que pones en el form.

Comment: si pues, era el adds y que le mandaba links/add